# Can I watch Apple TV on my PC without an Apple device or a credit card (using paypal)?

Tags: appletv, paypal

I do not own any Apple devices, but a friend recently recommended an Apple TV exclusive show to me which I'd like to watch. My goal is to subscribe using paypal since I don't have a credit card, and to watch shows in my browser or a PC desktop app, if available.

I have checked the list of available payment methods, and paypal is listed as being available in my country.

Immediately upon creating a new Apple ID on the Apple TV website, I was asked to enter credit card information, and there was no way to select a different payment option or to proceed without entering it. I then tried creating an Apple ID once more on Apple's main website, which worked, but in the account settings I also wasn't able to select any payment options other than credit card.

My friend then pointed me to iTunes, which I installed and logged into. Here, I was able to link up my paypal account and got the message that my Apple ID is now unlocked for use with Apple services. Thinking the problem was solved, I logged in once more into the Apple TV website, which now for the first time let me proceed past the login screen. Obviously, I still can't watch anything while not being subscribed to Apple TV, but when I tried that, I was once again asked to enter my credit card information, to "confirm that the owner of the account has allowed watching Apple TV through the internet", or something like that.

A Google search led me to a [support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210646) which made me think I could set up parental controls as an alternative to providing credit card information as a way of enabling the web version of Apple TV. Upon rereading it now, I can see that it doesn't actually say that, which explains why doing this also didn't help and I was asked for credit card information once more.

What am I missing? Is there any way to subscribe to Apple TV using paypal if I don't own an Apple device? Or can I do this on iTunes as well? So far, I was only able to find shows and movies for individual purchase on there, which didn't include the show I was looking for. Apologies if I'm missing something obvious, this feels like a new world to me.

(Note: I was made aware of an Apple TV app available in the Windows store, however this can only be installed on an Xbox, which I don't own either.)

Comment: Have you tried contacting [Apple Support](https://getsupport.apple.com/?caller=ikb) about this?  I think it might be the only solution for paying with Paypal.

Comment: @fsb Not, yet, I considered it but it looked like the only way was via phone appointment, so I thought it might make more sense to first ask for help online. I might contact them if there is no other way though.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. There is no Apple TV app for Windows, and I think you do need a credit card to subscribe to the service.
You might be able to get around the credit card problem if you purchase an iTunes gift card, and add that to your account. Then you will have a positive balance in your account and you might be able to subscribe with that.

But you still have the problem about the lack of access to the Apple TV app. This is available in a lot of places, including smart TVs, but not natively in Windows yet, AFAIK.

Comment: This confuses me a little, because there's an Apple TV website which looks like it would work similarly to Netflix for example, and generally anything that runs in a web browser should work on any OS. My freind actually confirmed to me that they were able to watch it there, although they also had to enter a credit card number (despite using a different payment method for their actual subscription). It appears to be used for verification for some reason, and I don't really understand why, or why there's seemingly no other way...

Comment: Huh, I had never seen the website https://tv.apple.com/, but I tested it and it does work just fine!  OK, then you just need to solve the CC problem.  Did you try an iTunes gift card?  I'm still thinking that it won't work for subscriptions, because they need to be able to bill _something_ when your gift card balance runs out.  Either that, or they suspend your subscription, but I'm fairly certain that they don't want that - they want to keep billing you, so you need a CC on the acct.

Comment: I think they could also keep billing me with paypal, at least it works that way on other sites. Maybe I should just get a credit card anyway, could come in handy in other places too I suppose.^^' I just didn't expect one to be required for this

Answer (score 0):

Buying or renting or borrowing an iPod touch or other low cost Apple device will let you get the best payment and account management experience for Apple TV. You also can take advantage of HDMI out on many devices to play the content to projectors and TV as well as try to consume content on the web at https://tv.apple.com/ via Unix or Windows or chrome os devices.

Specific benefits are a trusted device for account security and streamlined billing support.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915
- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-support/id1130498044